# shell script for multiplication table

Tags: shell

This is my code

#### mul.sh

```
echo "multiplication table"
echo "enter number"
read n
m=0
for((j=1;j<=12;j++))
do
echo -n -e " $j\t"
done
echo ""
echo 
for((i=1;i<=n;i++))
do
for((k=1;k<=12;k++))
do
m=` expr $k \* $i `
echo -n -e " $m\t"
done
echo ""
done
```

When I run this I got:

malathy@malathy:~/Desktop/fosslab/20084664/shell$ sh matrix.sh

multiplication table

enter number

2

matrix.sh: 5: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Your code doesn't match your sample output. You posted `mul.sh` and ran `table1.sh`.

Comment: what shell are you using?  What is your `#!` line?

Answer (score 1):

You're running a script that uses syntax that is not supported in the shell you're using. Either change the first line of your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

The Korn shell (at least some versions) and zsh also support the form of the `for` statement.

If you're using the Bourne shell (or something vary close like Dash), you need to change the `for` statement to use `seq` or `jot`:

```
for i in `seq $n`
```

or

```
for i in `jot $n`
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for multiplication simple and easy

```
echo Enter the multiplication number required:
read number
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
echo "$number * $i =`expr $number \* $i`"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax isn't supported in all shells:

```
for((j=1;j<=12;j++))
```

Try this instead:

```
for j in {1..12}
```

Comment: Are you running the right script? See John Kugelman's comment above.

Comment: The brace range expression isn't supported in all shells either.